# When I run my page it returns an error of null as if it is not capturing the information passed in

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a project called trash collector, from the Employee `Controller`, they will be able to confirm that a trash pickup was done and a charge amount will be added to the customer.

I created the logic below in the Employee Controller and created a button in the **Index** `View` to capture that confirmed pickup is now true and to add charge amount. It is capturing the charge amount, but it is not able to find my customer.

**I'm getting an Error:**

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Customer is `null`. I am not sure why it is showing as `null` because in the Index Logic I set it up for it to find Customers within the Zipcode of the Employee and it came back fine, but for the ConfirmPickup logic Customer is coming back as `null`, it is also showing that same error for my edit `actionlink` and details `actionlink`.

**Employee Controller**

Method below works and is bringing back customers:

```
 public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search)
        {
            var UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            Employee employee = db.Employees.Where(e => e.ApplicationId == UserId).FirstOrDefault();
            var filteredCustomer = db.Customers.Where(c => c.ZipCode == employee.ZipCode && c.PickupDay == DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString() && c.ConfirmPickedup == false);


            if (searchBy == "Pickup Day")
            {
                return View(db.Customers.Where(c => c.PickupDay == search && c.ZipCode == employee.ZipCode).ToList());
            }

            return View(filteredCustomer);
        }
```

**Method below does not work:**

`PickupConfirmed(Customer customer)` is returns `null`.  I have tried a `try`, `catch` still it returns `null`.

```
 public ActionResult PickupConfirmed(Customer customer)
        {
            //var UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var pickupConfirmedCustomer = db.Customers.Find(customer.Id);
            pickupConfirmedCustomer.AccountBalance += 19.99;
            pickupConfirmedCustomer.ConfirmPickedup = true;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

**Here is my Index View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Trash_Collector.project.Models.Customer>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Pickups For Today</h2>

<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Employees", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <b>Search By:</b> @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Pickup Day", true) <text>Pickup Day</text>
        @Html.TextBox("search") <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    }
</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("PickupConfirmed", "Employees", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StreetAddress)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.State)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ZipCode)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PickupDay)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StreetAddress)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.State)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ZipCode)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PickupDay)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Confirm Pickup" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
}
```

Comment: how do you pass your `customer` to `PickupConfirmed` action? Can you show us your frontend (JavaScript / web-form)?

Comment: Can you confirm by manual SQL query that the Customer from table `Customer` with `customer.Id` as the query value actually exists?

Comment: I added my HTML Index view, so maybe I am not passing in my customer into the PickupConfirmed?  My frontend looks like this, here is the link https://localhost:44305/Employees?searchBy=Pickup+Day&search=Saturday, once I click the confirm botton it will go to the ActionResult PickupConfirmed, I assuming that it is capturing the customer info already from when the botton is clicked.  But when I debug it, if i manually type in the Id number it adds the amount to the customer.

Comment: Yes it does exist because when I debug it and manually type in the Id number of the customer, the amount is then added to the customer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Your code
var filteredCustomer = db.Customers.Where(c => c.ZipCode == employee.ZipCode && c.PickupDay == DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString() && c.ConfirmPickedup == false);

change code
var filteredCustomer = db.Customers.Where(c => c.ZipCode == employee.ZipCode && c.ConfirmPickedup == false);


Maybe this portion is a problem 
 c.PickupDay == DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString() //is not equal
```